# sum of python array gives slightly different precision depending on array order

Tags: python, floating-point, sum

I would expect summing arrays to give the same number regardless of order. This test disagrees. What is causing this?

```
>>> sum([0.2, 1.0, 0.3939393939393939, 0.8846153846153846])
2.4785547785547783
>>> sum([0.8846153846153846, 1.0, 0.3939393939393939, 0.2])
2.478554778554779
```

This is making tests annoying to write as sometimes I am getting slightly different floats that cause assertions to fail.

Comment: Can you show the test? Some numbers are impossible to properly represent (PI is one for example).

Comment: I'm literally doing a raw assertion against a hardcoded value: self.assertEqual(value, 2.4785547785547783)

Comment: Although this doesn't directly answer the question, python unit `TestCase`s have an `assertAlmostEqual` method that handles these precision errors.

Comment: I don't see any asserts here.